# Calculate some values for each group of columns in Python with Pandas

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, dataframe, grouping

I have a DataFrame

Input

```
         A   B   C     D          
0      one  50   35  1.5  
1      two  30   40  2.0 
2      one  50   35  3.0 
3    three  40   35  3.5 
4      one  40   35  2.5
```

and I need to apply a math function on column D and fill with it a new column E, but before I need to group columns B and C. For example the math function will applied on values 1.5 and 3.0 for couple (50,35)

```
B   C   A     D
50  35  one   1.5
        one   3.0

40  35  three 3.5
        one   2.5

30  40  two   2.0
```

The values are calculated with a custom function that receive in input a numpy array and output an array with same length.

Output

```
         A   B   C     D   E          
0      one  50   35  1.5   4.5
1      two  30   40  2.0   4.5
2      one  50   35  3.0   3.5
3    three  40   35  3.5   6.8
4      one  40   35  2.5.  8.9
```

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe need [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) for return `Series` with same size as original `DataFrame`:

```
def func(x):
    print (x)
    #custom function, e.g. multiple all together 
    return x.prod()

df['E'] = df.groupby(['B','C'])['D'].transform(func)
print (df)
       A   B   C    D   E
0    one  50  35  1.5  4.50
1    two  30  40  2.0  2.00
2    one  50  35  3.0  4.50
3  three  40  35  3.5  8.75
4    one  40  35  2.5  8.75
```

Comment: @Ami Tavory - Thank you.